# What is the correct string specifier for _cmd?

Tags: nsstring, cmd, specifier

I use %s for _cmd, the latest XCode will generate an error "Format specifies type char * but the argument has type SEL". Checked documentation and couldn't find a clue. Anyone know the correct string specifier to use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never done Apple programming in my life, so bear with me, but a little Googling revealed easily that:

- to convert `SEL` to `NSString` use [`NSStringFromSelector`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromSelector)
- Then use the `%@` format specifier on that.

Comment: Thanks Christian, that's it. I didn't try to think converting it to string then use existing specifier.